MAUI add a existing database
I want to add a existing database to the MAUI project.
I am using the sqlite-net-pcl NuGet package in the project.
The database named Company.db3 within the Project. I add two place for trying.
I can't find the file path of the database.
How can I connect to the database?
I can't find the file path of the database.
Solution
Codes

Does this answer your question? How to pack existing SQLite Database in MAUI app

AppDataDirectory is used to get the app's top-level directory rather than  those files bundled into the app package.
